# Does a summation of two negative Gaussians with different standard deviations have a stationary point?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, normal-distribution, nonlinear-optimization

I wanted to find the critical points of the (simple!) equation:

$$ B(w; \mu_1, \sigma_1, \mu_2, \sigma_2 ) = 1 - e^{ - \beta_1 (w - \mu_1)^2 } - e^{ - \beta_2 (w - \mu_2)^2}$$

Where $\beta_i = \frac{1}{2 \sigma^2_i}$ usually called the precision parameter of the Gaussian or RBF. Anyway, what I wanted in particular to solve is:

$$ B'(w; \mu_1, \sigma_1, \mu_2, \sigma_2 ) = - \beta_1 (w-\mu_1) e^{ - \beta_1 (w - \mu_1)^2 } - \beta_2(w - \mu_2)e^{ - \beta_2 (w - \mu_2)^2} = 0$$

looking at the equation above I can't seem to find an easy way to make it zero. To make the first term zero we can choose $w = \mu_1 $ but that doesn't make the second term zero. Similarly, the other way round. However, it is super intuitively obvious that there are 2 minimums and 1 maximum since there are two dips defined by the upside down Gaussian (and in between them some maximum). I plotted this in mathematica to confirm that there must be these critical points and it seems I am correct:

[image]

however surprisingly I cannot find an easy way to express the critical points analytically. My initial goal is to at least have a way to express these 3 critical points for this 1 dimensional example if ever want to hope to find the critical points for higher dimensions.

Anyone knows how to do this?

---

My real intention is to be able to programmatically/systematically get the x-axis value between the two minimums that has exactly gradient equal to zero. Ideally able to generalize in higher dimensions.

For 1D and 2D I can sort of eye ball what the value should be by plotting things and then asking mathematics to tell me which value of $x$ leads to $\nabla f'(x) = 0$.

Comment: A note for readers: the variances in your equations are swallowed up in $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$.

Comment: @MarkFischler yes it is, sorry, it was annoying to write the 1 over and then not mess up with the latex. Let me incorrporate ur comment in my question and we can delete these comments.

Comment: [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817166/find-the-maxima-of-the-sum-of-two-gaussian-curves) is strongly related.

Answer (score 4):

Let us make the change of variable $x = w - \frac{\mu_1+\mu_2}{2}$. Thus, using the identity $\beta_i = \exp\ln\beta_i$, the equation $B' = 0$ rewrites as
$$
(x+\kappa) \exp\left(\ln\beta_1 -\beta_1 \left(x+\kappa\right)^2\right)
 + (x-\kappa) \exp\left(\ln\beta_2 -\beta_2 \left(x-\kappa\right)^2\right) = 0 \, ,
$$
where $\kappa = \frac{\mu_2 - \mu_1}{2}$.
After dividing by $\exp Q_\kappa(x)$, where
$$
2 Q_\kappa(x) = \ln(\beta_1\beta_2) - \beta_1 \left(x+\kappa\right)^2 - \beta_2 \left(x-\kappa\right)^2 \, ,
$$
one obtains the identity $x \cosh P_\kappa(x) + \kappa \sinh P_\kappa(x) = 0$, where
$$
2 P_\kappa(x) = \ln(\beta_1/\beta_2) - \beta_1 \left(x+\kappa\right)^2 + \beta_2 \left(x-\kappa\right)^2 \, .
$$
Therefore,
$$
x + \kappa \tanh P_\kappa(x) = 0 \, .
$$
Since $x\mapsto \kappa\tanh P_\kappa(x)$ is bounded and continuous, this equation has at least one solution.

- In the case $\kappa=0$, i.e. $\mu_1=\mu_2$, the only solution is $x=0$.
- In the case $\beta_1=\beta_2=\beta$, the equation rewrites as $$ 2\beta\kappa x = 2\beta\kappa^2 \tanh\left(2\beta\kappa x\right) . $$
  The complete set of solutions is
  $$
  x \in \left\lbrace
  \begin{aligned}
  & 0 \, ,\\
  & {\pm \frac{u^*}{2\beta\kappa}} \quad\text{if}\quad 2\beta \kappa^2 > 1 \, , \\
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
  $$
  where $u^*>0$ satisfies $u^* = 2\beta\kappa^2\tanh(u^*)$. The value of $u^*$ can be computed numerically with [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) or any other suitable numerical method. To do so, an appropriate initial guess is required. For instance, one can use the value $u^* \approx \sqrt{3}\sqrt{2\beta\kappa^2 - 1}$, which is deduced from Taylor series. It seems hopeless to get an analytical expression of $u^*$.
- In the general case where $\mu_1\neq\mu_2$ and $\beta_1\neq\beta_2$, we introduce the polynomial factorization
  \begin{aligned}
  2 P_\kappa(x) &= \left(\beta_2 - \beta_1\right) \left(x - x_0 - \Delta x\right) \left(x - x_0 + \Delta x\right) \\
  &= \left(\beta_2 - \beta_1\right) \left( \left(x - x_0\right)^2 - {\Delta x}^2\right) ,
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  \text{where}\quad x_0 = \frac{\beta_1+\beta_2}{\beta_2-\beta_1}\kappa \quad\text{and}\quad \Delta x = \frac{\sqrt{4\beta_1\beta_2\kappa^2 - (\beta_2-\beta_1)\ln(\beta_1/\beta_2)}}{\beta_2-\beta_1}\, .
  $$
  Maybe, a fine study would provide the exact number of solutions and their approximate location, but it seems hopeless to get an analytical expression of the solutions.

In order to find the abscissa of the local maximum, one can apply Newton's method and verify a posteriori that the returned value corresponds to a local maximum (the second derivative $B''$ must be negative). If $\beta_2/\beta_1\approx 1$, the initial guess $x=0$ can be used. Otherwise, if $\beta_2/\beta_1 \gg 1$ or $\beta_2/\beta_1 \ll 1$, the initial guess $x=\pm\kappa$ may be used.

Comment: Sorry if its a dense question but does your method generalize to more dimensions easily?

Comment: Also, the only unknown in my question is $w$, so the $\beta_i$'s, $\mu_i$'s etc are known constants. In part of the answer you assume $\beta_1 = \beta_2 = \beta $. Without that assumption does your answer change a lot? I guess if $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ is known one can always find the multiplicative factor that separates them i.e. the $k$ s.t. $\beta_1 = k \beta_2 $. I assume that case is encompassed by your answer, right?

Comment: Yes, the case $\beta_2/\beta_1\neq 1$ can be solved numerically. The only numerical workaround is when to decide if $|\beta_2/\beta_1| \gg 1$. This may be set after testing the method. Otherwise, a better estimation of the abscissa of the local maximum is needed. I'd suggest that you may have also a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452275/global-maximum-of-a-sum-of-gaussians) post, where a simple grid search is proposed. This method is robust, generalizes straightforwardly to any dimension, but has higher computational costs.

Comment: Do you mind explaining me what is so hard about getting analytic solutions to this? At least intuitively?

Comment: The equation $x + \kappa \tanh P_\kappa (x) = 0$ is a [transcendental equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) which cannot be solved in closed form in  the general case. Already the case $\beta_1=\beta_2$ is not completely solved in closed form.